# create a method that accepts an integer array that fills in the missing number between the elements

Tags: java, arrays

for example if the first slot in the array is a 2 and the second slot in the array is a 6, then you must insert 3,4,5 between 2 and 6. if the array that is passed into the method is {2,4,8,3} the method would return the array {**2**,3,**4**,5,6,7,**8**,7,6,5,4,**3**} (the numbers in bold are the values from the original array). So far this is what I have and I was just wondering if I was approaching it the right way. I know what I want to do but I cant seem to put it into code without getting an array out of bounds error. Please note that I am new to coding and I will appreciate anyone that takes time out of their day to help me even a little bit. thanks. All together I know that I will need to know all of the differences between each element. example {2,5} missing 3 and 4 difference = 2. and then add the difference to a new array with the length of the original array. Here is my current attempt to the problem.

```
public static int [] fillArray(int x[]){

    int max_diff = x[1] - x[0];
    int i, j;
    int counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) 
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < x.length; j++) 
        {
            if (x[j] < x[i] ){
              x[i] = x[i] - x[j];
                System.out.println(x[j]);
            }else if(x[j] > x[i]){


            }
        }
    }

    return x;

}
```

Comment: Arrays can't be resized in Java, which means you must create a new array somewhere.

Comment: Unless your specification says not to, I suggest using an arrayList instead, as it can expand in size.

Comment: 1
2
5
2
3
2
3
[1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 7, 3] not even close to what I want it to be

Comment: and what should be expected output of above input

Comment: well what I expected it to do: if x[0] is less than  x[1] then subtract the difference between them. and i thought it would move through the rest of the array since i have I++ and j++

Comment: am I wrong to think this?

Answer (score 0):

As per your provided example i have write a program that will fill the missing value, I am using `ArrayList` to hold the missing value instead of `Array` because of its dynamic size.

```
public class cn {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> fillArray(int x[]){

        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList();
    for(int i=0;i<x.length-1;i++)
    {
        if(x[i]-x[i+1]<0)
        {
            for(int j=x[i];j<=x[i+1];j++)
            {
                if(al.size()!=0){
                if((al.get(al.size()-1))==j){
                //al.add(j);
                }
                else
                    al.add(j);
                }
                else
                {
                    al.add(j);
                }


            }
        }
        else{
            for(int j=x[i+1];j>=x[i];j--)
            {
                if(al.size()!=0){
                    if((al.get(al.size()-1))==j){
                    //al.add(j);
                    }
                    else
                        al.add(j);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        al.add(j);
                    }
            }
        }


    }
    if(x[x.length-2]-x[x.length-1]<0)
    {
        for(int j=x[x.length-2];j<=x[x.length-1];j++)
        {
            //al.add(j);
            if((al.get(al.size()-1))==j){
                //al.add(j);
                }
                else
                    al.add(j);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(int j=x[x.length-2];j>=x[x.length-1];j--)
        {
            //al.add(j);
            if((al.get(al.size()-1))==j){
                //al.add(j);
                }
                else
                    al.add(j);
        }
    }

        return al;

    }
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int y[]={2,4,8,3};
    ArrayList<Integer> b = fillArray(y);
    for(Integer c : b)
    {
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program with method fun that solves your issue using ArrayList. Should do the trick ;)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    int[] abc = {2, 4, 8, 3};

    Integer[] result = fun(abc);
    for(Integer i : result){
        System.out.print (i + " ");
    }
    return;
}

public static Integer[] fun(int[] abc){
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i<abc.length-1; i++){
        int a1 = abc[i];
        int a2 = abc[i+1];
        if(a1<a2){
            for(; a1<a2; a1++){
                list.add(a1);
            }
        }else if(a1>a2){
            for(; a2<a1; a1--){
                list.add(a1);
            }
        }


    }
    list.add(abc[abc.length-1]);
    Integer[] result = new Integer[list.size()];
    result = list.toArray(result);
    return result;
}

}
```